# How to transfer gobs between programs

Tags: go, gob

I use the below code to create a gob file which go successfully executes

```
var METADATA = []interface{}{
     map[string]interface{}{...},
     map[string]interface{}{...},
     ...
} 

gob.Register(map[string]interface{}{})
gob.Register([]interface{}{})
file, err := os.Create("./thrift_metadata.gob")
if err != nil {
    return err
}
encoder := gob.NewEncoder(file)
err = decoder.Decode(object)
```

Below is the decoder compiled from a completely different codebase and debug binary, which fails.

```
    gobPath := path.Join(currentWorkingDirectory, "./thrift_metadata.gob")
    file, err := os.Open(gobPath)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    gob.Register(map[string]interface{}{})
    gob.Register([]interface{}{})
    decoder := gob.NewDecoder(file)
    err = decoder.Decode(object)
```

The decoding code fails with the following error:

```
gob: decoding into local type *[]map[string]interface {}, received remote type
```

Anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please provide a minimal verifiable example that others can run to help debug the issue. Right now your question doesn't have enough information to get you help. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This is a bad question. However I already solved the issue using another work around that avoided using gobs. I am voting to close.